# Firebase cloud messaging service worker issue (NextJS)

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

An error occurred while retrieving token.
FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
f —`_app-6e5ce7543176b121599c.js:1:8509`

create — `_app-6e5ce7543176b121599c.js:1:8994`

(anonymous function) —`_app-6e5ce7543176b121599c.js:1:639312`

asyncFunctionResume

(anonymous function)

promiseReactionJobWithoutPromise.

promiseReactionJob

I am getting fcm token from localhost. But the problem occurred when I try to build my next project and start or after deploying to the server.
I tried several solution from various sources.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically i was getting error because of new file structure.

```
import "firebase/compat/messaging";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
```

this is the new version import structure.